# Is it possible in Drupal Commerce to have 2 price fields according to role?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Is it possible to have 2 price fields, with manually added price?

Currently I have second price calculated. User with role "EUR_price" will see only EUR prices and others + anonymous will see USD. And this for product, in cart, order etc.

I'm not sure, if [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (and separate price field) is enough for this.

Comment: can you add more details to better explain that "currently I have second price calculated"? Like WHEN that calculation happens, and WHERE you eventually store the result of that calculation? about "enough for this": what do you mean by "this"?

Comment: Commerce should be able to do price conversion from one currency into another (but you might need additional modules for that). No need for two price fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have a different price depending on the role of the user? If you want to have a price based on user role then the [Commerce Pricelist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist) module can help with that.

From the module list

> Different prices for different roles or individual users
>
> Different prices for different quantities
>
> Different prices based on order date (like a time-limited discount)